# Execution failed for task ':x:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'

Tags: android, execution

I'm developing an app for my school, and when I run it, an error occurs:

> Execution failed for task ':Organitza el teu temps:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'.
>
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Organitza el teu temps:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'

Here is the build log:

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:Organitza el teu temps:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:preDefaultFlavorDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:preDefaultFlavorReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71900Library UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:prepareDefaultFlavorDebugDependencies
:Organitza el teu temps:compileDefaultFlavorDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:compileDefaultFlavorDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:generateDefaultFlavorDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Organitza el teu temps:mergeDefaultFlavorDebugResources
:Organitza el teu temps:processDefaultFlavorDebugManifest
:Organitza el teu temps:processDefaultFlavorDebugResourcesC:\Users\David\AndroidStudioProjects\Organitzaelteutemps\Organitza el teu temps\build\res\all\defaultFlavor\debug\layout\main.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello').
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Organitza el teu temps:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Organitza el teu temps:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.193 secs
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code, what it is supposed to do, what you already have found out debugging or checking the log and platform documentation?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project. I had this problem too and do that to fix this issue

Comment: Can you provide the build.gradle code?